# Missing tabs in FragmentHostTab Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

Developing tab based application in android, I have two tabs Tab1,Tab2 like ios always in the screen. Tab1 contains Activity1 which has a listview ,so when i click item on the listview, it should open another activity which contains some data , but i missing the tabs in the screen.

before i used `TabActivity`, now it is deprecated, i cant make use of `ActivityGroup`, so i want to use `FragmentTabHost`

How can i use `FragmentTabHost` to solve this issue or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can add supportv4 library, if you search on android developer page you cam get this .jar library... if you add that to your project build path.. then you cam use tht class.

Comment: I using supprt library for FragmentTabHost, able to do tabs by adding fragments. but when i click the listview items in one fragment, i want to show another with the tabs, tab is missing, hope you understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

add ListFragment in Tab.
when click item,you should replace another fragment by using Fragment Maneger &FragmentTransaction.
and you should use getChildFragmentManeger() to get FragmentManeger.

Comment: yes i doing the same, but the tab are missing when adding the fragments, I want tabs always on the screen. Do you have any example links for this?

Comment: sorry i don't have link.but this way is so easy. you should      runfragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.tabcontent,new OtherFragment()).commit in onClick.